# Como se diz «touch-typing» em português?

Tags: tradução, tradução-inglês, termos-em-inglês

*Touch-typing* é escrever sem olhar para o teclado.

Como se diz isto em português?
A única coisa a que consegui chegar foi «escrever sem olhar» ou «dactilografar sem olhar», ou «escrever/dactilografar cegamente»; mas não me parecem boas opções.

Comment: Does this seem right to Portuguese people - [http://www.typingstudy.com/pt-portuguese-2/](http://www.typingstudy.com/pt-portuguese-2/) ?

Comment: Yes, @mstechfreak . (And the question does not exclude Brasilian answers.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

«Escrever pelo toque» parece-me a opção mais perto do original. Encontrei [aqui](https://docs.kde.org/stable4/pt/kdeedu/ktouch/using_ktouch.html) uma ocorrência:

> O KTouch é um programa para ensinar a escrever pelo toque.
>
> O KTouch é um programa para aprender a dactilografar. O KTouch fornece-lhe o texto onde treinar, ajustando-se aos diferentes níveis, dependendo de quão bom você é. Ele poderá mostrar qual a tecla a carregar a seguir, e o dedo correcto a usar.

Em contextos como este, «dactilografar» também serve, porque ninguém é ensinado a dactilografar olhando para as teclas.